# What is this small hollow metal cylinder?

Tags: wooden-furniture, bolts

I've bought a flat-pack bed second hand, and it has one part missing. There are two boards I need to join, and according to the instructions I should hammer a short (about 4 cm) hollow metal cylinder into the hole in one, and then push it into the other, and then put a bolt through the cylinder (and fix it in place with a barrel nut). The cylinder is the missing part and I'd like to know what it's called so I can find a replacement. It's smooth both inside and out.

Here's a sketch of the situation in section, which is hopefully clearer: (I've omitted the barrel nut)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you post a photo of the part (assuming there were more than one in the kit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sleeve" or "Bushing" (sleeve being closer to correct for this application, but having both in hand will give you more things to try at the hardware store.) A section of pipe or tube might well do the job in the "not precut to length" materials section.

Are they all missing, or do you have one or more you can take with you to match?

Comment: Only one is missing.